# php function not working after include a file

Tags: php

function not calling or working when i include a link, without a include a file, function working properly

```
$AutoRunLink='C:\xampp\htdocs\banking1\index.php';   
$sql = "UPDATE automation_schedule SET
                                    start_flag='1',done_flag='0',attempt='$AutoAttempt',last_run='$CurrentTime',next_run='$AutoNextRun',run_server_from='$runServer'
                                    where ID=$AutoID";
                    $db->query($sql);
                    require_once '$AutoRunLink';
                    RestScheduleNextDay($db,$setRunNextDay,$CurrentTime,$AutoID,$runServer);
```

Comment: So what's in index.php? Is it returning a value correctly?

Comment: You are using single quotes on `require_once`, which will not expand `$AutoRunLink`.  Try using double quotes.

Comment: @mark index.php working perfectly

Comment: @BrandonHorsley I don't think he need to use any of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 
    require_once '$AutoRunLink';
to
    require_once $AutoRunLink;